# How to pass type Namespace.ID in preview parameter in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I am creating a subview in SwiftUI with few parameters. One of the parameters' type is Namspace.ID. So I have to pass the Namespace.ID type parameter through preview to see the view in Xcode canvas. I don't know how to do it. My codes look like this.

```
    struct BagView: View {
        var bagData:BagModel
        var animation:Namespace.ID
        var body: some View {
            VStack{
                ZStack{
                    Color(bagData.image)
                        .cornerRadius(15)
                    Image(bagData.image)
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .padding(20)
                        .matchedGeometryEffect(id: bagData.image, in: animation)
                }
                Text(bagData.title)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(.gray)
                Text(bagData.price)
                    .fontWeight(.heavy)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
        }
    }
    
    struct BagView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            BagView(bagData: BagModel(image: "bag1", title: "The Bag", price: "$123")) 
// I am getting an error here: Missing argument for parameter 'animation' in call
        }
    }
```

How can I see the view in Canvas by resolving the error?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is possible approach - use intermediate test/preview view:

```
struct BagView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    struct TestView: View {
        @Namespace var ns
        var body: some View {
            BagView(bagData: BagModel(image: "bag1", title: "The Bag", price: "$123"), 
                    animation: ns)
        }
    }
    static var previews: some View {
        TestView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes it is working, Can you please explain a little, what's happening? Thank You.

Comment: We just create preview-only wrapper view that provides all needed parameters to actually target view.

Answer (score 14):

The error tells you, that you forgot a parameter, since animation is a required and non-optional field.
So you need to add a value for the property "animation". Something like that:

`BagView(bagData: BagModel(...), animation: <valueHere>)`

EDIT:
You should be able to inject a Namespace value doing the following:

```swift
struct BagView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    @Namespace static var namespace // <- This

    static var previews: some View {
        BagView(bagData: BagModel(image: "bag1", title: "The Bag", price: "$123"), animation: namespace) 
    }
}
```

Comment: I know that, Thats what I am asking what to give as a parameter there.

Comment: yikes my fault, didn't read your question carefully. look at my edit

Comment: This is actually the more elegant solution. Too bad it takes a second read to get there :)

Answer (score 6):

Late Answer but I found one more option below (I came here on SO to search for Namespace)

add  **Namespace().wrappedValue**

example: -

```
struct TabItemView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        TabItemView(tintColor: .blue, inActiveColor: .gray, tab: .home, tabAnimation: Namespace().wrappedValue, activeTab: .constant(.home))
    }
}
```